# How to avoid duplicate javascript function definitions in several different web pages?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I'm maintaining existing code that is a little hacky. Let's say I have function A() which can be called in a callback method somewhere. In this part of the code, it is assuming that A() is already defined somewhere else (yes, I know, bad). I have several view pages in a C# MVC application that are responsible for providing a definition of A() (extra javascript is inserted into these pages). The problem is, some views will define A() to be empty, some will define A() to do something special, and some will not even define A(). The ones that do not define A() are obviously a problem. One way I could fix this is to simply define an empty A() function in these other views and call it a day.

The problem with this solution is that if someone creates a new view later on, then they will forget to add A() and then their view will have the same problem. I'm trying to figure out a somewhat clean way around this. One way I could do this is to have the code that actually calls A() perform a check to ensure A() is defined before calling it, but that also seems hacky to me. Plus, if someone did create a new view, they would never know that they should have provided their own definition of A(). So I'm not sure what to do. I'm new to JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: set A to an empty function in your master/layout

Comment: Messy designs often require hacky solutions. Live with it.

Comment: You should really look into modular programming.  http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html

Comment: do you have a common header, put your empty A() in that

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is fairly straighforward and you just have to decide what you want to allow vs. notify.

If it's acceptable for `A()` to not be present, then before calling it, you can just check to see if it exists to avoid an error:

```
if (typeof A === "function") {
    A(...);
}
```

Or, you could simple define a dummy one in one place to make sure that it is defined:

```
if (typeof A !== "function") {
    window.A = function() {};
}
```

---

If you think the designer really should be told early on that they should define `A()`, then you can make it clear that it should be defined:

```
if (typeof A !== "function") {
    // make some sort of error here
    // depending upon your typical audience, you can either put up an alert
    // or throw an exception
    throw new Error("Function A() must be defined");
}
```